# Does $\ln|x+2|=\ln|2x+4|$ and if so why so?

Tags: logarithms

Is $\ln|x+2|=\ln|2x+4|$? Is this right? I saw something earlier saying this was correct; my first instinct was no.

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Is $\ln(3) = \ln(7)$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too narrow to be of any future use.

Answer (score 7):

Its wrong. Take $x=-1$. You get $$\ln(1) = 0 \neq \ln(2).$$

Comment: Nice quick proof.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible what you saw before involved calculus?  They may not be equal, but they both differ by a constant: $\ln|2x+4|=\ln|x+2|+\ln2$. If one were to evaluate the integral $\int\frac{2dx}{2x+4}$, either $\ln|x+2|+C$ or $\ln|2x+4|+C$ would be considered correct.  But this does not mean that the $2$ logarithms are equal.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost correct. $\log |2x+4| = \log 2|x+2| = \log|x+2| + \log 2$.

Comment: Almost doesn't count in mathematics.....lol

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 "Almost" is used a lot in mathematics, although usually that specific word is not used. For example
$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log(x+2)}{\log(2x+4)}=1 $$
so they are asymptotically the same. But of course they are not equal as the questioner asks :-)

Comment: ...we have a saying in Ireland...nearly never milked a cow!!

Comment: @Eff - one thing I like about measure theory. For many things, "almost everywhere" is good enough!

Answer (score 1):

Or just take $x=0$, then $\log 2 \ne \log 4$.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted - it's correct.